# UIButton EXC_BAD_ACCESS on setTitle:forState

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller that's instantiated from IB. It contains a UIButton whose action creates a UIPopoverController whose delegate updates the title of the UIButton through:

```
- (void) popoverSelected:(NSString*)string {
    [self.sortButton setTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.sortPickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

`popoverSelected` is a delegate method for the `UIPopoverController`, which contains a simple `UITableView`.

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selectedSort = [_sortTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (_delegate != nil) {
        [_delegate popoverSelected:selectedSort];
    }
}
```

The popover is instantiated by the TouchUpInside action on the `self.button` through:

```
- (IBAction)sortButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    if (_sortPicker == nil) {
        // Create the picker view controller
        _sortPicker = [[SortPickerViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

        // Set this as the delegate
        _sortPicker.delegate = self;
    }

    if (_sortPickerPopover == nil) {
        // The colour picker popover is not showing. Show it
        _sortPickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_sortPicker];
        [_sortPickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:_sortButton.frame
                                            inView:self.view
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                          animated:YES];
    } else {
        // if it's showing, we want to hide it
        [_sortPickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        _sortPickerPopover = nil;
    }
}
```

This has no issues the first time the button's title is updated, but second time around I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when executing setTitle: in `popoverSelected`.

I can't see anywhere that I'm releasing the button accidentally (and the object definitely still exists at this point). The project is using ARC.

With NSZombies I've occasionally reached `[__NSArrayI valueRestriction] unrecognised selector sent to instance` which makes even less sense.

Are there any obvious approaches I can take to debug this further?

Comment: we would need more code or more information in order to help you..

Comment: Required code from - (void) popoverSelected:(NSString*)string method get call.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some supporting code.

Comment: How the popover presenting the second time? In the code you listed `_sortPickerPopover` is never nilled, thus second time you press the button it enters in the hiding code. I didn't test what happens if an already dismissed popover is dismissed again, but I could imagine that it causes some problems.

Comment: Is it possible to show the whole code?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of sortButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking `_sortPickerPopover == nil` to know whether to show it, you should check `[_sortPickerPopover isPopoverVisible]`. Also, I would put the construction code into autoloaders.

```
- (UIPopoverController *)sortPickerPopover
{
    if (!_sortPickerPopover) {
        _sortPickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.sortPicker];
    }
    return _sortPickerPopover;
}

- (SortPickerViewController *)sortPicker
{
    if (!_sortPicker) {
        _sortPicker = [[SortPickerViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

        // Set this as the delegate
        _sortPicker.delegate = self;
    }
    return _sortPicker;
}

- (IBAction)sortButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    if ([self.sortPickerPopover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.sortPickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
            [self.sortPickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame
                                                    inView:sender
                                  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                                  animated:YES];
    }
}

/***
 * NOTE: Delegate methods should always pass the calling object as the first 
 * object. Additionally, the name is not very descriptive of what is actually
 * being performed and does not use should/will/did naming conventions.
 * You should consider changing this method to something like:
 *  - (void)sortPickerViewController:(SortPickerViewController *)sortPicker   
 *               didSelectSortMethod:(NSString *)sortMethod
 **/
- (void)popoverSelected:(NSString *)string 
{
    [self.sortButton setTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.sortPickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Once these changes are made, the only other possible source of problems is the implementation of your SortPickerViewController. I'll look that over for you if you can post that view controller as well.